# Escaping a variable in an a href link

Tags: html, variables

I'm working on a Exchange Hub Transport Rule that applies signatures from variables that are pulled in from AD. Anyways I'm trying to get the email link working and I'm having an issue trying to escape quotes variable tags to include the proper format.

Variables included are %%Email%%, here is a link to all of them http://solarz.net/?p=31

```
Email:<a href=" %%Email%% ">%%Email%%</a>
```

The Email displays correctly but the link for the email address doesnt. Just cant figure out how to include the same %%Email%% for the link.

The Last %%Email%% displays correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Which email displayed correctly? And which wasn't? A little elaboration please...

Comment: edited post, the last one displays correctly, having issues with the one in the a href link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it using some escape characters.

```
Email:<a href="mailto:&#37;&#37;Email&#37;&#37;">%%Email%%</a>
```